# Multidocument transactions using doctine-odm for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm, php-mongodb

[doctine-odm](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/2.2/index.html) does not support native strategy for multi document transaction support as per this [document](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/2.2/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#limitation)

However, does anyone have figured out a workaround?

According to mongodb, we need to create a session and pass it to every query in the transaction to take control over full commit  rollback. [this](https://zgadzaj.com/development/mongodb/mongodb-multi-document-transactions-in-symfony-4-with-doctrine-and-mongodb-odm-bundle) implementation does the same thing but it does not work. I get error while passing session to the `->flush()` method.

**Error**
`The \"writeConcern\" option cannot be specified within a transaction. Instead, specify it when starting the transaction.`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    $callback = function (Session $session) { /** your code here */ } 
    $session = $client->startSession();

    with_transaction($session, $callback, [
        'readConcern' => new ReadConcern(ReadConcern::MAJORITY),
        'writeConcern' => new WriteConcern(WriteConcern::MAJORITY, 1000),
        'readPreference' => new ReadPreference(ReadPreference::RP_PRIMARY),
    ]);
```